# Symfony sfDoctrineGuard Password Encryption

Tags: php, symfony1, passwords, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

I have a Symfony 1.4 app using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin for users.

I need to move these users to a new system. After going through the documentation and code, I'm having trouble understanding how Symfony stores/checks passwords.

I want my new system (CakePHP) to store and check passwords the same way the old one does, so that nobody has to change their password.

How would I go about this? Can someone post a simple example?

Comment: The core of the checking is in PluginsfGuardUser.class.php; you may find the odd helpful detail in [this old question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935364/migrating-existing-users-and-passwords-to-new-symfony-sfdoctrineguard-user-syste), which is about migrating *to* Symfony. The approach I took was to use a standard plugin in the new system, but to add custom code to migrate user passwords from the old system at login -- might be worth bearing in mind as an approach. If you migrate at login, you have access to the unencrypted password, which is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just have to [dig into the cod](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/lib/model/doctrine/PluginsfGuardUser.class.php#L37)e, when sfGuard generate the password (`setPassword`) and when sfGuard check the password (`checkPasswordByGuard`).

They use an algorithm (by default `sha1`) to store the password which is salted.